# Dart: Use generic extension method, get NoSuchMethodError: Class 'xxx' has no instance method 'yyy'

Tags: dart

Implement a Kotlin Standard Library extension Function `let`:

```dart
extension KtStd<T, R> on T {
  R let(R f(T it)) => f(this);
}
```

And write a CLI sum calculator (The problem cannot be simplified), expect:

```
input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
output: 45

input: apple 1.2 banana 3.4
output: 4.6
```

Then code:

```dart
main() {
  stdin.readLineSync(encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')).split(" ")
      .map((s) => double.tryParse(s)).where((e) => e != null).fold(0, (acc, i) => acc + i)
      .let((d) => d % 1 == 0 ? d.toInt() : d)
      .let((it) => print(it));
}
```

When input `1 2 3`, getting error message:

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'double' has no instance method 'let'.
Receiver: 6.0
Tried calling: let(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic)
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      main (file:xxx.dart:xx:xx)
#2      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

In addition, if I change the `fold` function into `reduce`, giving the same input, getting error message:

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method 'let'.
Receiver: 6
Tried calling: let(Closure: (dynamic) => void)
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      main (file:xxx.dart:xx:xx)
#2      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

The dart version is:

```
Dart VM version: 2.8.2 (stable) (Mon May 11 15:06:42 2020 +0200) on "windows_x64"
```

Why I got these error messages? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart extensions are *static*.  They are syntactic sugar that is applied on types that are known at *compilation time*.  This means that extensions will not work on `dynamic` values where the type is determined at runtime.

Your long, chained expression ends up using `dynamic` types probably where you aren't expecting it.  One problem is that when you do `.fold(0, (acc, i) => acc + i)`, the parameter and return types of the callback are not deduced. (See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/731.) `acc` and the return type are thus assumed to be of type `dynamic`.

You can fix that by explicitly specifying a type for `fold`: `.fold<double>(...)`.

---

In your edited version of your code, you introduced a second problem:

```dart
extension KtStd<T, R> on T {
  R let(R f(T it)) => f(this);
}
```

You intend for `KtStd<T, R>` to depend on `let` to constrain `R`, but that's backwards. `let` is not a legal call without first making `KtStd<T, R>` an extension on `T`. `R` therefore is unconstrained and is assumed to be `dynamic`.  That then forces `let` to return `dynamic` too.

If possible, I suggest reverting to your earlier version where `let` is separately generic on `R`:

```dart
extension KtStd<T> on T {
  R let<R>(R f(T it)) => f(this);
}
```

---

You can more easily identify such errors during analysis by modifying your `analysis_options.yaml` file and setting:

```yaml
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
  language:
    strict-raw-types: true
```

Comment: But .when I use ```fold<double>(...)``` or ```reduce(...)```, still get the second error.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and it works for me when I use `fold<double>` or if I use `reduce`. (I am using Dart 2.8.2 on Linux.)

Comment: At any rate, if you're still getting errors, it means that you're still using `dynamic` in your chain.  I recommend running `dartanalyzer` or breaking up your expression into subexpressions so that you can easily inspect the static type of each.

Comment: I just found that there is a slight difference between the code here and the code I tested, and now it is consistent, you can try again.

Comment: Can you not use your earlier version?  I don't think your new version can work because there's no way to deduce what `R` is supposed to be in advance, so `R` is assumed to be `dynamic`.  That is, `KtStd<T, R>` must be deduced as an extension on `T` before `let` is invoked, so `let` can't constrain `R`.  You can observe this from a simple case: `var x = 42.let((y) => y);`, where `x` ends up being `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with generics this also works:

```dart
extension KtStd<T> on T {
  R let<R>(R Function(T) function) => function(this);
}
```

You extension method could have also been written in this way (see [lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_function_type_syntax_for_parameters.html)):

```
extension KtStd<T> on T {
  R let<R>(R Function(dynamic) f) => f(this);
}
```

I can't actually explain why, but you needed to specify the type of the function parameter to make it work correctly

Comment: Problem escalated！Your solution is useful, but I still curious that why I already give ```it``` the generic type ```T```, still get the errors, and why your solution works well?

Answer (score -1):

Try Object

```
extension KtStd on Object {
  Object let(Object f(it)) => f(this);
}

void main() {
  "12"
      .let((it) => it.toString() + "3")
      .let((it) => int.parse(it) + 1)
      .let((it) => print(it)); //124
}
```

Comment: Using `Object` prevents the code to be "analyzed" (you lose the type), so I think this shouldn't be the preferred solution